# Instance variables with a method in Java?

Tags: java, variables, instance

A triangle method has 3 instance variables.
int side1, side2, side3;

They give me the method I need to make as public Triangle (int s1, int s2, int s3)

Do I declare it as:

```
   public class triangle {

private int s1;
private int s2;
private int s3;
```

}

OR

```
  public class triangle (int s1, int s2, int s3) {
```

}

Thanks

I got this mixed up with a constructor. Figured it out, thanks guys.

Comment: It depends whether, in your first sentence, you mean "A Triangle _class_ has three _instance variables_", or "A triangle _method_ has three _parameters_".  What you actually wrote makes no sense.  Methods don't have instance variables.

Comment: The second segment of code doesn't even compile... A class cannot have arguments like that.

Comment: I think it is a good idea to follow a Java programming tutorial. It is important to understand the main concepts of the language before start coding :). You can start with http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if the method name is same as class name then it is called `constructor` which is called when a new object of that class is created.

```
public class Triangle {
    private int s1; // This are the private variable which
    private int s2; // are accessed by only object of
    private int s3; // class triagnle.

    public class Triangle (int s1, int s2, int s3) // This is a constructor which is called
    {                                              // when you create a object with new keyword
        this.s1 = s1;                              // like Triangle t = new Triangle(1,2,3);
        this.s2 = s2;
        this.s3 = s3;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please can we use capital letters for class names?  You are _teaching_ OP here.  Please be sure to teach him the good stuff.

Comment: @DavidWallace Yea sure. I answered referencing Ryan's code that's why I use small case letters.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class triangle {

    int s1;
    int s2;
    int s3;

    public triangle (int s1, int s2, int s3) {
        this.s1 = s1;
        this.s2 = s2;
        this.s3 = s3;

    }
}
```

Hope this helps.
Thanks

Comment: Now that you've dumped a piece of code onto an unexpected poster, you might like to explain to them why this approach would be suitable to their needs ;)

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is

```
public class Triangle {
 //atributes
 private int s1;
 private int s2;
 private int s3;

 //encapsulation
 public int getS1() {
        return s1;
    }
 public int getS2() {
        return s2;
    }
 public int getS3() {
        return s3;
    }
 public void getS1(int value){
        this.s1 = value;
    }
 public void getS2(int value){
        this.s2 = value;
    }
 public void getS3(int value){
        this.s3 = value;
    }
 //constructor
 public Triangle (int s1, int s2, int s3)
 {
  this.s1 = s1;
  this.s2 = s2;
  this.s3 = s3;
  //do something
 }
}
```

Comment: The best practice does NOT include using lower case class names.